# Does anyone know the source the KWFinder keyword research tool itself uses to build its data?

Tags: seo

We are trying to build some detailed and bespoke keyword analysis for a current project. The keyword research and analysis tool at kwfinder.com retrieves real-time search volume and ranking for any set of keywords, but their service does not provide sufficient granularity for this particular project. **Does anyone know the source the KWFinder keyword research tool itself uses to build its data so that we could see if it's something we could use?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's use Google Keyword Planner data, I don't know how, but may be via API (whitehat) or via scrapping(blackhat). But [Google hate such type of scrapper](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-calls-algorithm-monitoring-tools-blackhat-scrapers-24318.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The strength of your answer made me think this question should be reopened. Cheers!!

Comment: Google keyword planner is not free, is it?

Comment: avocado@It's free but did not show exact volume(it will show like 1k-10k as you can see in above SS) if you don't spend some money on advertisement. If you run campaign on Google adwords then you will see the data for free, but that might also take time because they want to know weather you're a real advertiser or scraper, so even if you spend some money then it will take time to see the exact volume.